# O que significa content:"\f0ed"?

Tags: css

Estou desenvolvendo um site a parti de um template pronto, ao inspecionar elemento e verificar qual imagem trocar encontrei o `Css` da seguinte forma.

```
.fa-cloud-download:before
{
  content:"\f0ed"
}
```

- O que significa esse `Css`?
- Como posso saber qual imagem é carregada a parti desse `Css`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A propriedade `content` no CSS é para adicionar algum conteúdo, por exemplo:

```css
div::after{
  display:block;
  content:"Hello World";
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

É importante notar que **a propriedade `content` só funciona se usada com os *pseudo-elementos* `:after` e `:before`**. Para saber mais sobre *pseudo-elementos* consulte o [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

O código `\f0ed` é um número hexadecimal que representa o endereço de um carácter em uma fonte ([que no caso é este carácter](https://fontawesome.com/v4/icon/cloud-download)). Por exemplo, para adicionar a letra `A` basta usar o código `\0041` que é o seu endereço.

```css
div:before {content:"\0041";}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<sub>Para saber o endereço de outros caracteres, basta olhar no [Mapa de Caracteres do Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/insira-tabela-de-caracteres-ascii-ou-unicode-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0) ou fazer uma rápida pesquisa na internet.</sub>

Não é recomendado adicionar caracteres especiais em códigos, como por exemplo nos `json` ou no nosso caso `content` do CSS, por isso utilizam-se os seus endereços hexadecimais, por exemplo o simbolo `♥`, que não existe no teclado brasileiro, mas pode ser adicionado com um atalho <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

```css
div:before {content:"\2665";}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Algumas fontes são criadas especialmente para a web, como são os casos das *Icon Fonts*. Essas fontes de ícones começaram a ser utilizada na web graças a propriedade `content`, pois poderiam ser referenciadas corretamente no código e poderiam trocar de cor, aumentar e diminuir o tamanho sem perder qualidade, diferente dos *sprites* (imagens com vários ícones) que pesavam bastante no carregamento das páginas e não eram "flexíveis" como as fontes.

Algumas fontes de ícones bastante utilizadas são:

- [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)
- [Icones do Twitter Bootstrap](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)
- [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/)
- [Fontello](http://fontello.com/)

Entre outras várias na web, basta pesquisar por `icon font` que encontrará dezenas...

A classe [`fa-cloud-download` pertence a fonte FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4/icon/cloud-download) (facilmente identificada pelo prefixo `fa-`), nela você pode [identificar vários ícones](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery), não é recomendado alterar o CSS fornecido por eles, pois quando for atualizar a biblioteca (constantemente são adicionados novos ícones) você perderá sua modificação.

Basta escolher o ícone desejado na "[documentação](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)" e alterar a classe no elemento que deseja mudar o ícone.

**Atenção:** para que o `content` funcione é necessário especificar de qual fonte é o endereço, por exemplo: `font-family: FontAwesome;`

Comment: Uma das melhores respostas do SOpt-Br.

Answer (score 5):

Você esta selecionando o elemento de classe `fa-cloud-download`, com o `pseudo-elemento` `:before` esta dizendo ao navegador que quero fazer algo no início deste elemento, a propriedade `content` serve para inserir conteúdo dinâmico no `HTML`. Nesse caso, estou inserindo um elemento de código: `\f0ed` que seria um `icon` (ou `glyphicon`).

Códigos onde pode encontrar mais `icons`: [Link](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)