# Como colocar &raquo e &laquo no ::before?

Tags: css, css3

Estou precisando colocar  um » `&raquo` e um « `&laquo` no atributo `:before` de um determinado, elemento.

Como faço isso no CSS?

```
ul.breadcumb > li:after{
    content: '&raquo'; /** Isso aqui não funciona **/
}
```

Comment: Tenho certeza que da com Jquery.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que significa `content:"\f0ed"`?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75162/o-que-significa-content-f0ed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer isto utilizando: `\00BB`. Por exemplo:

```css
ul.breadcumb > li:after{
    content: "\00BB";
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcumb">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Se quiseres que a seta seja apontada para a **esquerda**, utiliza: `\00AB`

<sub>Fonte: [Unicode Character 'RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bb/index.htm)

Fonte: [Unicode Character 'LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00AB/index.htm)</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela informação adicional do `&laquo`

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar o código hexadecimal. Os códigos &xxxx são entities do HTML e não CSS, você deve utilizar um código alternativo.

```css
ul.breadcumb > li:after{
    content: '\00BB'; /** Isso aqui funciona **/
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcumb">
    <li>teste</li>
    <li>teste</li>
    <li>teste</li>
    <li>teste</li>
    <li>teste</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 pelo `/** Isso aqui funciona ***/`