# O Que esse código CSS Faz ?

Tags: css, css3

Esto olhando alguns trechos de código na internet pra um aprendizado mais profundo de CSS, e vi esse código contido em um menu e gostaria de saber qual a funcionalidade dele.

```css
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [O que significa content:“\f0ed”?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75162/o-que-significa-content-f0ed/75166#75166)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essa regra irá criar um elemento especial (chamado de [pseudo elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos)) antes e depois de quem possuir a classe `.nav`. Nesse caso em específico, parece ser um tipo de [*clearfix*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554043/4056678), colocando dois espaços entre o elemento e no `:after` é aplicada a propriedade `clear:both`.

Provavelmente porque os itens desse menu usam a propriedade `float` que tem um comportamento chato de se trabalhar e pode ser visto [nesse artigo da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). Essa técnica de flutuar elementos vem diminuindo, pelo menos é o que eu acompanho. Como alternativa `display:inline-block` é utilizado e mais recentemente o [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), porém este último ainda tem suporte limitado.

#### SEM CLEARFIX:

```css
nav { border: 2px solid red }
a { float: left; border: 2px solid blue }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
</nav>
```

#### COM CLEARFIX:

```css
nav { border: 2px solid red }
a { float: left; border: 2px solid blue }

nav::after,
nav::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: table
}

nav::after {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
</nav>
```

- [**`after`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/:after)
- [**`before`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/:before)
- [**`content`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: Essa resposta está muito boa, acredito que faltou explicar o porque do `display: table` que gera uma célula anónima e aplica formatação em bloco evitando assim que as margens do topo e do fundo se combinem em uma só (margin collapse) http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente, ele irá antes e depois (before/after) acrescentar um espaço e exibirá no formato de tabela (display: table;).

Comment: Não entendi o que seria exibido como tabela.

Comment: Geralmente isso serve para limpar o `float:left`, se não me engano

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de formatação do CSS é utilizado muitas vezes em icones de FrameWorks CSS já prontos, por exemplo o bootstrap.

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
  content: "\2a";
}
.glyphicon-plus:before {
  content: "\2b";
}
```

Esse código por exemplo expõe na tela um asterisco em forma de ícone/imagem e o outro expõe um outro elemento. Quando conectado ao BootStrap (http://getbootstrap.com.br/)