# Qual é o efeito que a propriedade overflow: hidden está fazendo no código?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho esse código bem simples ai em baixo. Só que o problema é que se eu tirar a propriedade `overflow` do código simplesmente, some a cor de fundo e colocando ela novamente ela aparece porque isso está acontecendo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

   ul
   {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333333;
   }

   li
   {
      float: left;
   }
   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Navigation Manu</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to style the list horizontally, to create a navigation menu:</p>

<ul>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>News</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
   <li>About</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

O problema é que vc está usando `float:left` nos elementos filhos do `container`. Quando vc coloca `float` nos Filhos o Pai perde a referencia dos valores do `box-model` desses elementos, pois agora eles estão "flutuando" no dom.

> **O uso da propriedade `overflow` com valor diferente de `visible`** (seu valor padrão), **criará um novo contexto de formatação de bloco**. Isto é tecnicamente necessário para evitar que um conteúdo flutuante que entre em contato com o objeto dentro da área de rolamento e quebre as linhas do conteúdo

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Leia também sobre o que é [**Block formatting context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Uma das técnicas para resolver isso é colocando `overflow:auto` no `container` Pai, assim, mesmo o Filho tendo `float` ele não vai "fugir" ao escopo do Pai. Outra técnica para corrigir isso é usando o famigerado [Clearfix](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118509/o-que-esse-c%C3%B3digo-css-faz)

Aqui o Pai é o Box com borda vermelha, e os Filhos são os Box Azul com `float`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Float serve para vc "flutuar" elementos um ao lado do outro. A `div` é um elemento do tipo bloco e funciona como um **[box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)**, ou seja ela ocupa 100% da largura da tela e aceita valores de `margin`, `padding` e `border`. Logo, pela `div` ocupar 100% da largura da tela ela não deixa que outras `divs` ficarem ao seu lado, para "corrigir" isso usava-se o `float`

Porém, usar `float` tem uma série de problemas, o `float` faz com que um elemento pai perca a referência do *box model* do filho que tem `float`, para prevenir esse comportamente usa-se a técnica do `overflow` ou do `clearfix`

**Técnica do ClearFix**

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

/* clearfix */
ul::after,
ul::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: table
}

ul::after {
    clear: both
}
```

```html
<h2>Navigation Manu</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to style the list horizontally, to create a navigation menu:</p>

<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>News</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Leitura recomendada:** [Float vs. inline-block. Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332116/float-vs-inline-block-quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-cada-um/332144#332144)

Comment: Opa, valeu ajudou muito!!! tava meio confuso sobre o overflow.

Comment: @LeandroNascimento sem problemas meu caro, fico feliz em ter ajudado!