# Por que quando eu coloco float right a cor do meu fundo desaparece?

Tags: html, css, float, background

criei um cabeçalho, com um fundo, texto e imagem.
quero deixar o texto na esquerda e a imagem a direita.
coloquei o float:right mas ai o fundo acaba sumindo.

```css
.fundo1 {
  background: linear-gradient(266.22deg, #BFF4FF 38.6%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 163.18%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imglabelle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header id="fundo1" class="fundo1">
  <h1 class="tdbb">
    Tudo para o seu bebê<br> Entregas para todo o Brasil
  </h1>
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/gif/100/100" class="imglabelle">
</header>
```

Comment: A imagem deveria ficar alinhada à direita abaixo do texto mesmo ou lado a lado?

Comment: a direta lado a lado

Answer (score 2):

Amigo o problema não é o `float`, é o `position`, vc colocou como `absolute`, então o ponto de referência dele é o body nesse caso... para o ponto ser o *container* pai é preciso que o pai tenha `position: relative`, assim o filho em absoluto fica relativo ao pai.

Além disso, faltou vc colocar um `top` no filho... vc só colocou `right`, mas tb é indicado colocar explicitamente uma orientação vertical

```css
.fundo1 {
  background: linear-gradient(266.22deg, #BFF4FF 38.6%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 163.18%);
  overflow: hidden;
  
  position: relative;
}

.imglabelle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 10px;

  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="fundo1" class="fundo1">
  <h1 class="tdbb">
    Tudo para o seu bebê<br> Entregas para todo o Brasil
  </h1>
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/gif/100/100" class="imglabelle">
</header>
```

---

**Observação sobre o `float`**

Em alguma situações quando vc usa `float` em um filho o *container* pai perde a referência do filho no *content-flow*, com isso o pai não reconhece a altura do filho. Uma técnica amplamente usada para corrigir isso é o `clearfix`, vc pode ler mais sobre isso nessas duas questões.

[Float vs. inline-block. Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332116/float-vs-inline-block-quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-cada-um)

[Qual é o efeito que a propriedade overflow: hidden está fazendo no código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381021/qual-%C3%A9-o-efeito-que-a-propriedade-overflow-hidden-est%C3%A1-fazendo-no-c%C3%B3digo)

Exemplo, repare que o pai perdeu a referência de altura dos filhos. Nesse código abaixo vc só consegue ver o BG vermelho do pai pq eu dei um `padding`, mas se vc remover o `padding` a cor de BG do pai some.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #f00;
  padding: 2px;
}
.container div {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Acha que vale a pena colocar aqui que ao usar o float a altura do elemento pai deixa de respeitar o tamanho da imagem?

Comment: @Woss sim, no caso dele não aconteceu por causa do tamanho do próprio texto, mas vou deixar um pergunta sobre `clearfix` como referência