# UL não segue fluxo normal da pagina

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tendo um problema no desenvolvimento de uma pagina especifica do meu site, onde por algum motivo uma Ul está saindo do "fluxo normal", usando as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do chrome deu para verificar que ele sai do body como na imagem abaixo:

[image: A Ul são as imagens que tem <a> dentro de <li> e aparecem depois do menu]

Basicamente quero tentar arrumar isso pra fazer o Ul retornar ao fluxo normal, porque qualquer coisa após o Ul aparece por cima da Ul como se ela não estivesse ali.

---

***Codigo HTML da pagina***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edgar Müeller - Home</title>
<link href="estilo/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="estilo/obras.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Inicio do menu !-->
<script>
  function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");
  }
  </script>
<nav id="all">
<input type="checkbox" id="chec">
<label for="chec">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</label>
<div class="bg"></div>
<nav id="principal">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li id="sub10">
          <div class="a">Obras <span>+</span></div>
          <nav id="obras">
              <ul>
                  <li ><a href="3dpavement.html">3D Pavement Art</a></li>
                  <li ><a href="evolution.html">Evolution</a></li>
                  <li ><a href="thecaves.html">The Caves</a></li>
                  <li ><a href="ark.html">The Ark</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
      <li><a href="estilo.html">Estilo das obras</a></li>
      <li id="sub11"><div class="a">Contato <span>+</span></div>
        <div id="contato">
        <form action="?valid=1" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
        <p class="white">Nome*:</p> <p><input type="text" name="nome" required placeholder="Nome completo"></p> <br>
        <p class="white">E-mail*:</p> <p><input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail para contato"></p> <br>
        <p class="white">Empresa:</p> <p><input type="text" name="empresa" placeholder="Empresa representada"></p> <br>
        <p class="white">Posição:</p> <p><input type="text" name="posicao" placeholder="Seu cargo"></p> <br>
        <p class="white">Mensagem*:</p> <p><textarea name="mensagem" cols="40" rows="8" required placeholder="Sua mensagem"></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar">
        </form>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</nav>
<!-- Fim do menu !-->

<!-- Inicio dos conteudos !-->
<section id="espaco">&nbsp;</section>
<section class="titulo"><center><h1><u>3D</u> <u>PAVEMENT</u> <u>ART</u></h1></center></section>
<br>
    <ul class="ultable">
        <li class="ProjectLink">
            <a href="#" class="ateste">
                <img src="imagens/Preview/The_Crevasse_preview.png" class="ProjectPreviewImg">
            </a>
            <br>
            <center>
                <p>The Crevasse</p>
            </center>
            </li>
            <li class="ProjectLink">
            <a href="#" class="ateste">
                <img src="imagens/Preview/The_Crevasse_preview.png" class="ProjectPreviewImg">
            </a>
            <br>
            <center>
                <p>The Crevasse</p>
            </center>
            </li>
            <li class="ProjectLink">
            <a href="#" class="ateste">
                <img src="imagens/Preview/The_Crevasse_preview.png" class="ProjectPreviewImg">
            </a>
            <br>
            <center>
                <p>The Crevasse</p>
            </center>
            </li>
            <li class="ProjectLink">
            <a href="#" class="ateste">
                <img src="imagens/Preview/The_Crevasse_preview.png" class="ProjectPreviewImg">
            </a>
            <br>
            <center>
                <p>The Crevasse</p>
            </center>
            </li>
            <li class="ProjectLink">
            <a href="#" class="ateste">
                <img src="imagens/Preview/The_Crevasse_preview.png" class="ProjectPreviewImg">
            </a>
            <br>
            <center>
                    <p>The Crevasse</p>
            </center>
            </li>
            <li class="ProjectLink">
            <a href="#" class="ateste">
                <img src="imagens/Preview/The_Crevasse_preview.png" class="ProjectPreviewImg">
            </a>
            <br>
            <center>
                <p>The Crevasse</p>
            </center>
        </li>
    </ul>

<br>
<script>
setTimeout(function resposta(){
var url_ = new URL(location.href);
var valid = url_.searchParams.get("valid");

if (valid == 1){
        window.alert("Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso! Vamos analisa-la e tentaremos entrar em contato por e-mail o mais breve possivel")
}
},500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

***CSS (estilo.css) - nem tudo desse CSS está sendo usado nessa pagina, já que ele é um "geral" pra outras paginas que estão funcionando***

```
/* Formatação padrão */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

body {
    font-family: "Agency FB", Arial, SansSerif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-image: url("../imagens/The_Crevasse_003.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}
footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

.caixas{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 10px ridge rgb(100,100,100);
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .caixas{
        border: 10px ridge rgb(200,200,200);
    }

.psobre{
    font-size:1em;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.psobre:hover{
    font-size:1.2em;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

footer{
    background-color:#bbb;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
/* Inicio do css icone do menu hamburguer */
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Fim do css do icone do menu hamburguer */

/* Inicio Menu hamburguer */

#chec {
    display: none;
    /* esconde o checkbox */
}

#chec:checked ~ #principal {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Faz o menu aparecer e reaparecer */
}

#chec:checked ~ .bg {
    display: block;
}

#teste{
    height: 120vh;
}

#principal {
    background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.7);
    /* cor do fundo do menu */
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    /* unidade base do viewport, pega 100% da pagina */
    left: -200px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .4s;
    /* Faz a transição/animação do menu */
}

#obras {
    background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.7);
    /* cor do fundo do sub-menu */
    height: 100vh;
    /* unidade base do viewport, pega 100% da pagina */
    left: -100%;
    transition: all .4s;
    position: relative;
    /* Faz a transição/animação do menu */
}
#contato {
    background-color: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.7);
    /* cor do fundo do sub-menu */
    height: 100vh;
    /* unidade base do viewport, pega 100% da pagina */
    left: -100%;
    transition: all .4s;
    position: relative;
    /* Faz a transição/animação do menu */
}

a:not(.ateste) {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    color: white;
}

a:hover:not(.ateste) {
    /* hover do menu */
    background-color: rgb(176, 224, 230);
    color: black;
}
.a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    color: white;
}

.a:hover {
    /* hover do menu */
    background-color: rgb(176, 224, 230);
    color: black;
}

label {
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul:not(.ultable) {
    top: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
}

ul li span {
    float: right;
}

.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    display: none;
}
.bg2 { /* escurece a home para destaque */
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: block;
}
#all{
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index:10;
}


#sub10 #obras {
    top: -70px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#sub10:hover #obras {
    left: 100%;
    pointer-events: initial
}

#sub10 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 66px;
}

#sub11 #contato {
    top: -70px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#sub11:hover #contato {
    left: 100%;
    pointer-events: initial;
    width: 350px;
}

#sub11 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 66px;
}

/* inicio do form */
#form1{
    top:90px;
    position: relative;
    left:25px;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .4s;
}
#sub11:hover #contato #form1{opacity:1;}

.white{
    color: #fff;
}

#enviar{
    font-family: "Agency FB", Arial, SansSerif;
    font-size:1em;
    position:relative;
    top: 50px;
    left:110px;
    background-color: rgb(176, 224, 230);
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #3F8E99;
    transition: all .4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#enviar:hover{
    background-color: #3F8E99;
    border-color: rgb(176, 224, 230);
    color: white;
    transition: all .4s;
}

/* fim do form */

/* Fim Menu hamburguer */

/* CSS do conteudo */
#espaco{
    position:relative;
    height: 55px;
}
.conteudo{
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 50px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 50px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 50px;
}
.conteudo2{
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
}
.conteudo p{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.titulo{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size:1.3em;
}

.moldura{
    border: 10px ridge rgb(100,100,100);
}

.estiloimg1{
    width:450px;
    height:auto;
}

.img100{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
/*
#mueller{
    bottom:340px;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .4s;
}
#mueller:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .4s;
}
*/
/* Inicio do CSS do slide show */
    * {box-sizing:border-box}

/* caixa do Slideshow */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 56%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border:  7px solid #777;
}

/* Esconde as imagens por padrão*/
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* botão "proximo" e "anterior" */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* posição do botão "proximo" */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* Ao passar o mouse, adicione uma cor de fundo preto com um pouco de transparência */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(50,50,50,0.8);
}

/* texto da legenda */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* texto dos numeros (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Os circulos */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* animação de transição */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
/* mudança de cor da legenda */
.legenda{
    color: #111;
}
/* Fim do css do slide show */

/* Inicio do CSS da pag sobre */

.foto{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    border: 10px ridge rgb(100,100,100);
    width:180px;
    height:188px;
    background-image: url("../imagens/mueller/Edgar_Mueller.jpg");
    transition: all .4s;
    webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4ss;
}
.foto:hover{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    border: 10px ridge rgb(100,100,100);
    width:180px;
    height:188px;
    background-image: url("../imagens/mueller/Edgar_Mueller_vetor.fw.png");
    transition: all .4s;
    webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
}

/* Fim do CSS da pag sobre */
```

---

***CSS (obras.css)***

```
/* teste */

    .relative{
        position:relative !important;
    }

.ultable{
    position: relative !important;
    width: 55%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.ProjectLink{
    position:relative !important;
}

    .ProjectLinkContainer .ultable,.ProjectLink{
    position:relative !important;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}

.ateste{
    display:block;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.ateste:hover{
    position:relative;
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0));
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}



    /* teste */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara sem ofensas, eu não sei onde vc estudou, ou se pegou algum material muito antigo como referencia, mas estou aqui te dando uma dica ok! Esquece que `float` existe. `Float` não é para construir layout.

Repare na imagem abaixo veja que eu primeiro coloco uma borda no `body`, ai vc vai ver que tem conteúdo para fora, esse conteúdo que vaza é o conteúdo que está com `float`. Para corrigir isso eu coloquei `overflow:auto` no pai, assim o pai reconhece o tamanho dos filhos, mesmo que eles estejam com `float`. Mas isso é um "hake", não vejo como uma prática, vc pode fazer outras gambiarras do tipo [**ClearFix**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118509/o-que-esse-c%C3%B3digo-css-faz). Mas o ideal mesmo é que abandone o `float` e use o `flex`.

**Resposta:** Então para corrigir o problema basta colocar `overflow:auto` no CSS da `<ul class="ultable">`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu cara, mas deixa eu perguntar, o que seria esse flex que você citou?

Comment: Pode começar por aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceitos_Basicos_do_Flexbox existe uma infinidade de material sobre isso, tenho certeza que um dia vc vai voltar e agradecer pela dica, float é coisa de década de 90 :D, concentre seus estudos em FlexBox e Grid Layout (Grid https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

Comment: Boa, @hugocsl. Realmente esses float só atrapalham. O float na verdade é para flutuar o elemento para os lados, correto ? Você disse que não é correto usar o float para layout. Então para que utilizamos os floats ?

Comment: Grid é vida xD.

Comment: @JucianoVictor grid vale ouro, o problema é que ele tem muitas variáveis e o povo acaba complicando algo simples, mas realmente grid+flex é melhor que bacon 

Comment: @ThiaguinhoEmbasamento float é uma herança maldita desse época http://prntscr.com/pqmam9 repare onde sinalizei com a seta, float é para colocar um elemento "flutuando" e o que está flutuando não está ocupando espaço no "chão". ou seija o que vem abaixo acaba não respeitando o boxmodel do elemento que está com float. Mas tecnicamente, o float é para fazer o flow do conteúdo "contornar" o element, é um recurso tipográfico e não de layout, é para ajustar texto e não blocos de conteúdo. Como tudo a tecnologia tb avança no CSS/HTML, e hj temos o grid e flex que resolve isso de forma muito melhor!